# How to print expanded variables from Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Given `Makefile` in which `libdir` is defined as `libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib`, how to print its final (expanded) value?

Running `make -pns | grep -e "^libdir" | uniq` prints `libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib`, whereas I rather want to see `/usr/local/lib` (provided that `exec_prefix` is `/usr/local`).

Is it possible without appending that `Makefile` with yet another rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
printf 'include Makefile\nfoo:\n\t@echo "$(libdir)"\n' | make -f - foo
```

Note that the concept of *final value* is difficult to define with make. It may depend on the specific target...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what you mean by "a final value". For *recursive* variable it's a literal string `$(exec_prefix}/lib`. And the expansion only takes place when the variable is referred with `${libdir}`.

However *simple* variables are immediately expanded. So `libdir:=${libdir}` and `make -np` will produce the desired result. But other way it's not possible.

BTW. You can write a common "printing" rule like this (seen in GMSL):

```
print-%:
    @echo value of "$*" is "$($*)"
```

And then just do `make print-libdir`